# Image Crop component

Tags: delphi, image-processing, components

I need a simple component to do image crop, to use inside an option where user must select an image, photo, or logo to represent them.

I already done some search with Google but found nothing good.

I would something with source code.

Comment: http://exampledelphi.com/delphi.php/tips-and-tricks/crop-image-with-drag-the-mouse/

Comment: Open source isnt compatible with copy protection from [this][1] question, by the way.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467391/what-is-the-best-way-to-stop-an-application-being-copied-and-used-without-the-own

Answer (score 3):

A TRect, [DrawFocusRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162479%28VS.85%29.aspx) and some handling of OnMouseDown, OnMouseMove, OnMouseUp for allowing user interaction to draw the cropping frame

and

[BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370%28VS.85%29.aspx) to do the actual cropping after the user is happy with the selection he made.

And look, there is an example which uses those same ideas: http://exampledelphi.com/delphi.php/tips-and-tricks/crop-image-with-drag-the-mouse/.

God bless!

Comment: raised exception class EInvalidOperation with message `'Can only modify an image if it contains a bitmap'`.

Comment: @Kermia Use a .bmp instead of jpeg/png/etc. If you really need support for those other formats convert them to a TBitmap which is outside of the scope here. See http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0042.htm

Comment: Example does not exist anymore

Answer (score 3):

Try ImageEn from http://www.hicomponents.com/main/. It does what you want and a lot more. It is free, but not sure if you can get source with it.